# Would it be possible to overload the onDraw method in Android?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am trying to draw objects on a canvas in Android. For instance, for a filled triangle, I define the values for the triangle in one class and using a button click, I would like to call the canvas from another class  with the triangle displayed on it.

My issue is that I am having a hard time passing the values from the class to the onDraw(Canvas canvas) method. I am thinking of overloading the method. Has anyone done this before?

Thanks.

"Re-edited based on the responses below!!"

This is the code that I am calling when I click the button from another class. However,despite the fact that the triangle values are called, the onDraw() method is not being called. Where am I going wrong?

```
public class MyView extends View{

Path path = new Path();
Paint paint = new Paint();

public MyView(Context context) {
    super(context);

}

public void setPath(Point a, Point b, Point c){

    path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
    path.moveTo(a.x, b.y);
    Log.d("MYVIEW","pointA" +a.x);
    Log.d("MYVIEW","pointB" +b.y);
    path.lineTo(b.x, b.y);
    path.lineTo(c.x, c.y);
    path.lineTo(a.x, a.y);
    path.close();

    postInvalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

     super.onDraw(canvas);

    paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    paint.setColor(android.graphics.Color.RED);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    Log.d("ONDRAW","inside onDraw");
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);       
}
```

}

"How I am calling the MyView Class"

```
Point pointA = new Point();
        pointA.set(x, y);
        Point pointB = new Point();
        pointB.set(m, n);
        Point pointC = new Point();
        pointC.set(b, c);

        MyView view = new MyView(this.context);

        view.setPath(pointA, pointB, pointC);
```

Comment: Any thoughts,anyone? I would appreciate it immensely.

Comment: be carefull if `x,y,m,n,b,c` are not correct and the view is drawing outside the visible area - try to set them to some small integers as a try

Comment: Sherif, the values are fine because they are actually displayed in the Logs. However, it is the Log in onDraw that does not get called.

Comment: ok .. change `postInvalidate()` to `invalidate()` ! whats the problem ! Be carefull if you are blocking the UI thread.. nothing will be drawn

Comment: I changes it Sherif, however, what exactly would cause UI thread blocking? As I have not changed the code in any way.

Comment: You should check when you call MyView if the execution ends or blocks after it

Comment: I am sorry to drag this along Sherif, but the code seems fine from here!!

Comment: Maybe you should do `path.moveTo` and `path.lineto` inside onDraw? :( I wish i can help more

Comment: Thanks Sherif, you have been of great help. I will tinker for a bit and post my progress once made. Really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 1):

I think that the idea of calling an `onDraw()` method yourself directly is flawed in the first place, because `onDraw()` is the method that the *system* calls when it wants to render your View, passing it the `Canvas` to do so. Telling the system that you want the View to be re-rendered is done by calling `invalidate()` on that View (or `postInvalidate()` from a non-UI thread) and then the system will eventually call that View's `onDraw()`.

What you should be doing is either providing your custom View with a reference to an object that holds the data that will affect what's drawn, or alternatively create some 'setter' methods in your custom View so that the View itself is the object that holds that specific data. It really all depends on your application. Then you'd call `invalidate()` on that View.

Extremely simplistic examples of the above:

```
Triangle mTriangle = new Triangle( ... vertices here ... );
mCustomView.setTriangle(mTriangle);
mCustomView.invalidate();

Or:

mCustomView.setTriangle( ... vertices here ... );
mCustomView.invalidate();
```

You could perform the `invalidate()` in the setter method as well if you like to simplify it still. This is probably how a `TextView`'s `setText()` method works: it sets the text into a variable, and then calls `invalidate()`.

Comment: Trevor Page, thank you for your reply. It is similar to Sherif's so I am going to tweak my code to see if I will get the results thanks.

Comment: Trevor Page, I have tweaked a little bit but I am still stuck. Please advise.

Comment: First thoughts: (1) It would be better to make it obvious in your initial question that you've edited your code in response to answers or comments, as otherwise it's confusing for people who read it later. (2) You don't need to be calling `super(...)` in your `onDraw()`. (3) Is `setPath()` being called from a non-UI thread? If not, it should be calling `invalidate()`, not `postInvalidate()`.

Comment: Thanks Trevor, I will re-edit in a moment. However, even after setting to invalidate(), since I am calling from non-ui thread, the onDraw() is not called in my class.

Comment: OK, cool. When you say you're still stuck, how far is it actually getting? In other words, are you finding that even though `setPath()` is being called, `onDraw()` is never called?

Comment: How are you adding this View into the hierarchy? Post your complete example code including Activity and XML layout file.

Comment: @TrevorPage let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2153/discussion-between-user788511-and-trevor-page)

Comment: Trevor, I have posted how I am calling the view. I can not however, add the xml layout file as I am not really using it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do this:

```
public class yourDrawingView extends View{

//bla bla bla

int triangle_detail1;
int triangle_detail2; //and all you need to draw the triangle

public void setTriangle(int d1,int d1){ //etc give the function the parameters she needs
    triangle_detail1 = d1;
    triangle_detail2 = d2;
    //ETC

    //finally
    invalidate();
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    //draw your triangle
}
```

Comment: Sherif, this is something I envisioned. Let me tweak my code abit and i will provide some feedback

Comment: Sherif, I have tewaked but I am still stuck, please advise

Comment: @user788511 Are you adding MyView to the root or xml?

Comment: Sherif I am not sure what your question means. However, I am not implementing xml in anyway.

Comment: are you doing something like this: `MyView A = new MyView(this);` `something.addView(A);`?

Comment: show us the code and please if there are exceptions show them to us

Comment: Sherif, there are no exceptions. I will add how I am calling the MyView class.

Answer (score 0):

The buffer of a custom view is not persistant, you have to draw everything for each frame, while SurfaceView is persistant but it has two buffers which complicates things.

You can easily do what you want if you would draw all your objects to a bitmap and then draw that bitmap on the view's canvas. Then you can created overloaded methods for your objects.

Another way to do it which is good for undo feature is to make each object a class as Trevor sugggested and then add these objects into an ArrayList.

When onDraw just iterate through the ArrayList and draw all objects. You can then easily add or remove objects.

An example:

```
class Triangle{
 public PointF p1;
 public PointF p2;
 public PointF p3;
 public boolean filled; 
 public int tColor;
 public boolean remove;

  Triangle(PointF p1,PointF p2, PointF p3, boolean filled, int tColor){

   this.p1 = p1;
   this.p2 = p2;
   this.p3 = p3;
   this.filled = filled;
   this tColor = tColor;

  }

}
```

Create a triangle and add it to an arraylist:

```
ArrayList<Triangle> triangles = new ArrayList<Triangle>();

Triangle triangle = new Triangle(new PointF(1,1),new PointF(2.2f,2.2f),new PointF(3.3f,3.3f), true, Color.BLUE);

triangles.add(triangle);
```

in onDraw(Canvas canvas) for the view:

```
for (int i = triangles.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

   Triangle triangle = triangles.get(i);
   if (trinagle.remove){
       triangles.remove(i); //remove object if condition met
   }else{
       drawTriangle(triangle, canvas);
   }
}
```

Then you in drawTriangle method you just draw the lines etc on the passed canvas..
I hope this gives you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks Lumis, let me consider the resposes from Sherif and Trevor before responding to yours.